# Using jQuery toggle an input to be disabled depending on select option change?

Tags: jquery, select, input, onchange

I have a select dropdown:

```
<select class="selector">
  <option value="Yes">Enabled</option>
  <option value="No">Disabled</option>
</select>
```

And an input:

```
<input type="text" class="tester" value="test">
```

What I am trying to do is toggle the disabled property on the input when the select option changes. So if the option selected is enabled, the input should be enabled and visa versa.

Following the notes for [jQuery change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) I have tried to get this to work but it just doesn't want to. Not sure what I am doing wrong here as it seems like it would be straightforward:

```
$( ".selector" )
.change(function () {
  var selector = $("selector").val();
  if (selector == 'No') {
    $('.tester').prop( "disabled", true );
  } else {
    $('.tester').prop( "disabled", false );
  }
})
.change();
```

Could someone point out to me where I have gone wrong here in my logic? Thanks in advance!

[A fiddle is available here](https://jsfiddle.net/517s881e/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a bad selector inside the callback function:

```
$( ".selector" )
.change(function () {
  var selector = $('selector').val(); // The problem is here
  if (selector == 'No') {
    $('.tester').prop( "disabled", true );
  } else {
    $('.tester').prop( "disabled", false );
  }
})
.change();
```

Try changing it to this:

```
$( ".selector" )
.change(function () {
  var selector = $(this).val(); // Leverages "this" instead of repeating the selector
  if (selector == 'No') {
    $('.tester').prop( "disabled", true );
  } else {
    $('.tester').prop( "disabled", false );
  }
})
.change();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/517s881e/6/

Comment: Just use `$(this)` instead of repeating the selector.

Comment: Thanks @Vince that was spot on, it was just the typo. I thought that I might be going mad as I am not good with JavaScript but it looked like it should work out :)

Comment: Winning answer as it is more detailed and clearly indicates the problem and solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your selector when reading the .val() is incorrect, try this

```
 $( ".selector" )
.change(function () {
  var selector = $(this).val();
  if (selector == 'No') {
    $('.tester').prop( "disabled", true );
  } else {
    $('.tester').prop( "disabled", false );
  }
})
.change();
```

If it's still not working, debug in your browser at "var selector" assignment, or alert the value to see what you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in one of the selectors, you are using `selector` so a `.` is missing. Change it to `.selector`, `$(this)` would also work.

```js
$( ".selector" )
.change(function () {
  var selector = $(".selector").val(); //HERE IS THE CHANGE. ALSO: $(this)....
  if (selector == 'No') {
    $('.tester').prop( "disabled", true );
  } else {
    $('.tester').prop( "disabled", false );
  }
})
.change();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the attribute `disabled` instead of the property.

```
$( ".selector" )
.change(function () {
  var selector = $(".selector").val();
  if (selector == 'No') {
    $('.tester').attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
  } else {
    $('.tester').removeAttr( "disabled");
  }
})
.change();
```

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/517s881e/4/

Also, you had a problem in your `selector` selector. You should use this when you can so the code is easier to understand

```
$( ".selector" )
.change(function () {
  var selector = $(this).val();
  if (selector == 'No') {
    $('.tester').attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
  } else {
    $('.tester').removeAttr( "disabled");
  }
})
.change();
```

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/517s881e/5/

Comment: Although using attribute will work, `disabled` is technically a property and not an attribute.  And it has nothing to do with what is causing the issue here.

Comment: Thanks a heap, makes more sense but if I am not mistaken attr() was replaced with prop()?

Comment: Please post your answer here, not just a fiddle link.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity Do not be mislead -- you were perfectly correct in using `.prop()`.  The reason the fiddle provided in this answer works is because it corrects the selector issue that has been mentioned in other answers.

Comment: @Vince You're right, my wrong. It's just that I had problems in the past while using `prop` instead of `attr`. I thought it had two mistakes, while it only had one. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: @IndigoIdentity I believe you can use both, but don't mind me, the real problem was the selector

Comment: @Barmar Did it, but I still think it's wrong because of what Vince said. Should I delete this?